# Исключить узел с определенным тегом

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
jQuery(element).contents().each(function() {...});
```

Можно как-нибудь исключить здесь узел с определенным тегом? Обрабатываю таким образом текст на странице, и нужно обработать все кроме тега `pre`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Кроме селектора [`:not`](https://api.jquery.com/not-selector/), есть еще метод [`.not`](http://api.jquery.com/not/).

```
//все содержимое .content исключая <pre> отмечаем красным
$('.content').contents().not('pre').each(function(){
    $(this).addClass('red')
});
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gadgmrpt/)

Comment: Зачем `contents()` и цикл? `$('.content :not(pre)').addClass('red');`

Comment: Совершенно не нужны. Только ради примера использования. Код из вопроса.

Comment: @Deonis, в моем коде внутри цикла выполняются еще и некоторые проверки, так что без него вряд ли обойтись удастся.

Answer (score 0):

`$('div:not(.lBox)')` - вернет все div-элементы, кроме тех, которые принадлежат классу lBox.

`$('div:not(#bigBang)')`- вернет все div-элементы, кроме элемента с идентификатором `bigBang`.

`$('input[id]:not([type=text])')`- вернет все input-элементы с заданным идентификатором, кроме текстовых полей.